# Change locale for Place Autocomplete

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using this code :

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

To display autocomplete results for google places.

I'm using two different devices in two different languages and i get two different results because the device languages.

How do I set language/locale for the results ?

The javascript equivalent is to add language to the params, But how do I do it in android ?
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&language=XX

Comment: Have you found any soution ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like currently there is no way to force the locale or regional bias in Google Maps Android API and Google Maps Places API for Android. I can see the following feature request in Google issue tracker that was filed exactly for this purpose:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63829150

Feel free to add star in the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications. Hopefully, one day Google will implement it.